# SSRS Report Total is incorrect

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I want total of debit from invoice table and credit from payment table. 
credit total display correctly while debit is incorrect.
I use  Group on invoice# invoice table field.

It seems that it sum twice a value.

[image]

Can anyone tell me where i am wrong.

The data is stored in two tables. Invoice, which holds the Invoice# and Debit amount, and Payment which holds the Credit and Payment#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can do this in SSRS which is very simple just go to the `Debit` cell right click and select Add Total something like this in the following example, I have added a total for `Unit Price` column.

[image: Adding a Total For a colulmn In SSRS]

Answer (score 1):

Because you are grouping by Invoice#, two rows exist in the dataset for Invoice# 1 (one for each of the Credit amounts). This means the Debit amount is duplicated across each row and when you Sum the column, it counts it twice.

You would be better off getting the Sum values for Credits by including a Subquery.

```
SELECT InvoiceNo, Debit
,(SELECT SUM(Credit) FROM Payments P WHERE P.InvoiceNo = I.InvoiceNo)
FROM Invoices I
```

The above assumes that you may have multiple Debits per Invoice#. The below assumes that there can only be one Debit per Invoice#

```
SELECT I.InvoiceNo, Debit, SUM(ISNULL(Credit, 0))
FROM Invoices I
LEFT JOIN Payments P
ON P.InvoiceNo = I.InvoiceNo
GROUP BY I.InvoiceNo, Debit
```

Without knowing your table names, the above is just a guess, but hope this helps.

Comment: Hi 
I have only two table which are invoice and payment.
debit is invoice field while credit is from payment
how can change your query

Answer (score 0):

The summation is as a result of all the rows in the respective groupings.
From your example, it counts the 1 twice only that it does not show the values except for the credit values.

To handle this, you can use nested aggregates: I.e, if using a table matrix, with say a parent and a child group, then you can do it as below:

=SUM(MAX(Fields!debit.Value,"Child_group_Name"))

This worked for me.

The link below may give more insight to this:

https://www.magenium.com/resources/ssrs-reports/